# How to create an ellipsoid

Tags: ros-kinetic, gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I would like to create an ellipsoid in Gazebo (and use it as static, and only visual, no collision). Reason for that is that I want to show an object and the minimum-volume ellipsoid enclosing the object. I have the algorithm to calculate the ellipsoid, but I don't know how to spawn it in Gazebo (no problem for a sphere, but I can't find any ellipsoid model). Is there any way to do so ?
I'm using Gazebo7 and ROS Kinetic.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15564/how-to-create-an-ellipsoid/) by [Kittenator](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3096/kittenator/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-03-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Unfortunately, there isn't yet an ellipsoid primitive in Gazebo. The only way to use one right now would be to create one with a CAD program and export it to a mesh format supported by Gazebo 7 (COLLADA, STL or OBJ).

Here's a tutorial explaining how to import meshes using SDF:

http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=attach_meshes&cat=build_robot

And here's an issue tracking the feature request for ellipsoid support. You could vote for that issue:

https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/522/consider-support-for-ellipsoid-geometric

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kittenator](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3096/kittenator/) on 2017-03-13**:
Thank you for the answer, concise and clear. I voted for the issue and will be waiting for the ellipsoid update !